# Google Analytics metrics to find total number of users who came to site via ad campaign

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way to determine how many users visited my site via ads of my site posted on other websites?

Answer (score 0):

By default these will show up as referrals in the channel and all traffic reports. To get more granularity you'd have to use campaign parameters in your ads url. You can create properly tagged url via Googles [url builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) which has some documentation on the various parameters.